# How to call correctly a String splitting method from another class?

Tags: arrays, spring, class, methods, split

I`m trying to access the Spring splitting method from Person class in Main class, but it doesn't show me only the last result from the text. It`s working very good when i`m integrating System.out.prinln in Person class, in method body but In this homework i`m not aloud to use System.out in Person class, only in Main class. The result must split the text in "Surname , Name , City". Where am i doing wrong? Thank you!

```
public class Person {
    public String surname;
    public String name;
    public String city;


    public Person(String text) {

        String[] person = text.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < person.length; i++) {
            String surname = person[i].split("[.]")[0];
            String name = person[i].split("[./]")[1];
            String city = person[i].split("/")[1];

            this.surname = surname;
            this.name = name;
            this.city = city;
        }


    }
    }
```

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person p1 = new Person("John.Davidson/Berlin Michael.Barton/Rome Ivan.Perkinson/Munich");
        System.out.println(p1.surname + p1.name + p1.city);
// the result is the only the last persons info  
}
}
```

Comment: Your for loop in the `Person` constructor writes to the same `this.surname` field on each loop iteration. That's why you only see the last person info.

Comment: It must give me something like : John Davidson Berlin    Michael Barton Rome   Ivan Perkings Munich      on separate lines. So the problem is in the spliting constructor... any suggestions? And why is it working perfect when i insert System.out in the constructor body?